# htaccess: redirect file in subfolder to same file in root with https and no www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

been looking around, and perhaps i'm just misinterpreting, but I can't seem to find a clear solution to this problem.

I had my webpages installed to a sub folder called `h`. I have recently moved the files and folders to the root and I would like to redirect all requests made to the `h` folder to be redirected to the root with some other conditions (see below).

`mydomain.co.za/h/index.php/contact-us` must redirect to `https://mydomain.co.za/index.php/contact-us` (no `/h/` and `https://` included)

`mydomain.co.za/h/index.php/order` must redirect to `https://mydomain.co.za/index.php/order` (no `/h/` and `https://` included)

All conditions below should be considered:
1) If URL contains sub folder `/h` or `/h/` to redirect to root
2) If URL contains `www.` to have it removed
3) if URL contains `http://` to change it to `https://`
4) if specific page was requested (eg. `index.php/contact-us` to have all the above performed (first) then include the page

Please note that the filename (index.php or eg. controller.php) must be present before `/contact-us` or `/order` else the contact-us or order pages won't show. I believe that the index.php file controls which pages to load.

----Update----
I have this short term fix in my .htaccess to make URL have `https://` but it only redirects if the URL does not contain the sub folder `h` and does not include the requested page, just sends all requests to root. I can see why it only does this but I don't know how to fix it to do what I require (as mentioned above). Lack of rewrite understanding.

`#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mydomain\.co\.za$ [NC,OR]`
`RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off`
`#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomain.co.za/$1 [R=301,L]`

---

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: You have many requirements listed here but why we cannot see your own attempts?

Comment: As @anubhava said, what did you try so far ? Also, look at your point number 4: it does not make sense. You'll always have `http` or `https` (even if browser does not show it) because it's the web protocol used

Comment: @JustinIurman You are absolutely right. my bad. changed point number 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `DocumentRoot/.htaccess` have this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

# ignore sub domains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+\.[^.]+
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Better to remove all other `.htaccess` from any sub folders.

If for some reason you have `/h/.htaccess` then inside `/h/.htaccess` have this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /h/

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com/$1 [L,NE,R=302]
```

Comment: What would I need to do if I don't want to have the domain and ext hard coded? i.e. in the line `RewriteRule ^ http://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]` I want `domain.com` to be what ever was in the original requested address?

Comment: We can avoid hardcoding `domain.com` but that will be 2 rules: 1 for `http->https` and 2 for `www -> non-www`. Let me know if you're fine with this and I will update the answer.

Comment: whatever it takes. I have added a parked domain to my hosting account and would like the same rules to apply to both domains with the exception that domain and ext remain the same as requested. I assume that if I no longer want to have the `www.` removed from the URL, that I simply remove the first condition?

Comment: ok answer updated. Yes you don't need 1st rule if you don't want `www` removal.

Comment: Also will these rules also affect requests like `mail.domain.co.za`?

Comment: Yes rules will affect all the domains now.

Comment: This might be a problem because I have CNAME records that point to other servers. eg. `mail.domain.co.za` points to google servers...The rules must only apply to eg. `domain.com` and the `www.` subdomain but not to other subdomains

Comment: ok check updated rules for ignoring `mail.domain.co.za` requests. Also I suggest you not to change the nature of this problem via comments section. It is always better to focus on one problem in one question and create new question for more problems.

Comment: Tnx. I will keep that in mind. I was actually using `mail.domain.co.za` as an example case, I have lots of CNAME records pointing to other servers (mail, calendar, etc.) I've make a slight change to your code to exclude `mail.domain.co.za` from being redirected to include all sub-domain requests to be ignored except `www.` my changed code: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]` This seems to work but in your opinion, is this the correct way of doing it?

Comment: But `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.+)$ [NC]` will also block: `domain.com`

Comment: I have pasted your code and now I get `Internal Server Error`. The url seems to be correct. server error log shows `.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters`

Comment: There was a typo, try again now.

Comment: That fixed the error...but now redirect to `https://` is not working if URL contains `/index.php/order`

Comment: I think I have supported this question well beyond the original problem. As I suggested earlier post a new question with all the details and I will try to answer it there.

Comment: I cleared the .htaccess file, tried url, obviously didn't redirect, pasted your code again, tried it and seems to work. strange. I'll keep checking. If I encounter another issue then I will post a new question. But thank you very much for all the effort. I deeply appreciate it, and please forgive me for moving off-question.

Comment: Turns out it didn't work. Redirect only happened when `www.` was present (and `http` was off), when url didn't have `www.` the other rules were ignored. I changed the order of the rules by moving the first rule to the bottom. That seems to have did the trick. Will monitor though. Tnx again.